# Why does the compiler report an error when running this C code for merging two arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

Two arrays of integers nums1 and nums2 in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n denoting the number of elements in nums1 and nums2, respectively.

Merge nums2 into nums1 so that the merged array is also in non-decreasing order. The final merged array is stored in the array nums1.

The following is my code:

```
void merge(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int m, int* nums2, int nums2Size, int n){
    int index = 0;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int result[m + n];
    while(index < m + n) {

        if(nums1[index1] <= nums2[index2] && count1 < m && index1 < nums1Size) {
            count1++;
            result[index++] = nums1[index1++];
        }
        else if(count2 < n && index2 < nums2Size) {
            count2++;
            result[index++] = nums2[index2++];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m + n; i++) {
        nums1[i] = result[i];
    }
}
```

And it reports an error of `AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address`. Is my index access out of bounds?

It's called by this:

```
int main() {
    int num1[6] = {1,2,3,0,0,0};
    int num2[3] = {2,5,6};
    merge(num1, 6, 3, num2, 3, 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", num1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how it is called? Is the amount of allocated space for `nums1` at least `m + n`?

Comment: Stack space is extremely limited on some platforms, like Windows, so be wary of this sort of thing for non-trivial sizes of `m` and `n`.

Comment: Tangential (not part of your problem): You  don't need both `index1` and `count1` — they store the same value at the end of each iteration; ditto for `index2` and `count2`.  The argument `num2Size` provides no value — as long as you can safely `assert(num2Size >= n)`.  The argument `num1Size` should be checked to ensure you can safely `assert(num1Size >= n + m);`.  You then don't need to check either `num1Size` or `num2Size` later in the merge loop.  If you take the sanity checking seriously, you need to return an error indicator from the function to indicate problems.

Comment: Normally, an array merge function has three loops: one to merge while both arrays still have data, and then one to merge residual data from the first array and one to merge residual data from the second array.  Only one of the latter two loops actually copies any data.  You can do it with a single loop and more complicated conditions, but that's usually not as good as the three loops.

Answer (score 1):

When I study your while loop:

```
while(index < m + n)
```

If neither `(nums1[index1] <= nums2[index2] && count1 < m && index1 < nums1Size)` holds nor `(count2 < n && index2 < nums2Size)` then you got some potential for an infinite loop since index will never get incremented. Maybe it works. It just looks complicated.

Consider this as a traditional merge loop.  It'a assumed that `merged` is sized to be `nums1Size+nums2Size`.

```
void merge(int* nums1, size_t nums1Size, int* nums2, size_t nums2Size, int* merged) {

    int index = 0;

    while (nums1Size > 0 && nums2Size > 0) {
        if (*nums1 < *nums2) {
            merged[index++] = *nums1++;
            nums1Size--;
        }
        else {
            merged[index++] = *nums2++;
            nums2Size--;
        }

    }

    while (nums1Size > 0) {
        merged[index++] = *nums1++;
        nums1Size--;
    }

    while (nums2Size > 0) {
        merged[index++] = *nums2++;
        nums2Size--;
    }

}

int main() {
    int num1[3] = { 1,2,3};
    int num2[3] = { 2,5,6 };

    int merged[6];

    merge(num1, 3, num2, 3, merged);

    // if nums1 was allocated to big enough to hold merged, you can copy it back into it here.

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d ", merged[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is my index access out of bounds?

**Yes**, it can be, depending on the inputs.  Even if we suppose that `nums1` in fact points to enough space to accommodate at least `n + m` elements, and `nums2` in fact points to enough space to accommodate at least `m` elements, the evaluation of `nums2[index2]` in this `if` condition can cause an out-of-bounds access:

> ```
>         if(nums1[index1] <= nums2[index2] && count1 < m && index1 < nums1Size) {
> ```

That happens when `m` is exactly the number of elements accessible via `nums2`, and the last element of `nums2` is merged before the last element of `nums1` is.  That won't happen with the specific input you presented, but it would be easy to modify that into input that does trigger that issue.

And even if it's never an out-of-bounds access *per se*, as a result of `nums2` having more than `m` elements, it can still be an incorrect access.  The merge should not be making decisions based on the value of `nums2[m]`.

As others have observed to you already, the conventional pattern for a merge involves three loops:

- one that handles the merge up to the point where one of the sources is exhausted, and
- two more, one for each source that copies the tail of that source into the result.  On any given merge, one of these two will perform no work.

It *can* be done with a single loop, but the logic needed to do it correctly is tricky.  In contrast, it's easy to follow the logic and confirm the correctness of a good three-loop merge.